# User attributes missing from login Azure B2C token in UWP app

Tags: uwp, azure-ad-b2c

I have a UWP app that gets an Azure B2C token and uses it to access a protected web api.

The user flow is set to return the display name as part of the token. However authResult.Account.Username is null after the user is authenticated.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I checked the token with the debugger at https://jwt.io/. The token does include the username. It's just not being extracted in the app...

Comment: ...the token includes the username as the 'name', in case that is important.

Comment: ...yes that is important. Username is left empty deliberately in b2c because of limitations of social accounts. So you need to parse the token yourself or configure it differently... -- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/issues/64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, username is omitted by design in b2c. It passes the username as name in the token. Decoding it to retrieve this value in the app solved the problem. I decoded it using https://github.com/greenygh0st/JWT-Decoder (.net standard) which was very simple to use, notwithstanding a typo in the readme [JwtDecoder should be Decoder].